# Bind an object with HasConversion

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, binding

Given the dummy entity `MyClass`

```cs
namespace MyProject.Entities
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public MyType TypeId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the it's type that I don't want to put in the database

```cs
namespace MyProject.Enums
{
    public class MyType : SmartEnum<MyType , int>
    {
        public static MyType Type1 = new(1, "Type1", 10, 1973);
        public static MyType Type2 = new (2, "Type2", 20, 1974);
        public static MyType Type3 = new(3, "Type3", 30, 1975);

        public int? LanguageKeyId { get; set; }
        public int SortOrder { get; set; }

        private MyType(int value, string name, int sortOrder, int? languageKeyId) : base(name, value)
        {
            LanguageKeyId = languageKeyId;
            SortOrder = sortOrder;
        }
    }
}
```

I added the configuration for `MyClass`

```cs
public class MyClassConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<MyClass>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MyClass> builder)
    {
        if (builder == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));

        builder.ToTable("MyClass", "Service");
        
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.Property(e => e.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(255);
        builder.Property(e => e.MyTypeId).HasConversion(e => e.Value, e => MyClassType.FromValue(e));
    }
}
```

As you might have noticed, I have a LanguageKeyValue (for phrase keys) and LanguageKeyValue (for phrase translations) tables that where I store all my phrases with translations.

Is it possible to use `HasConversion` method in `MyClass` configuration to somehow add LanguageKey object into `MyClass.TypeId` object so that I can get the translated type name?